# shift+enter shortcut not working for vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, interactive

I am currently using Python on a remote server with vscode. I always use ctrl+enter or shift+enter for running the selected line or section. However, this stopped to work several days ago. When I press shift+enter, it will open two command terminals: one for the python interactive terminal, and the codes are sent to the other one, which does not have python. Right-clicking and manually selecting the desired command give the same results.
[image]

The screenshots of these two terminals are shown below.

The one with python interactive window:
[image]
The one receiving the codes: of course bash cannot execute python codes :-(
[image]

Here are keyboard shortcut settings sorted by highest precedences:
[image]
[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!!!!

Comment: then I encourage you to give the answer there an upvote ([/help/why-vote](/help/why-vote)) and close this question as a duplicate of that one ([/help/duplicates](/help/duplicates)).

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is resolved by installing a older version of Python extension. Maybe there are multiple versions of python on that server and `2022.8.0` version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).